# Creating and Comparing Hashing Windows certutil and external hash libraries

Tags: hash, windows

I have a question about checking hashes and what is the best utility for it.

Seems like you can use some external programs like `md5sum` or `sha1sum`. But can't you just use (on Windows) `certutil -hashfile`? What are the advantages of one over the other?

Comment: As long as you can generate the same hash, it doesn't matter. Note that various tools produce different hash types ...

Comment: Also, if you are comparing a hash made from one tool with that made by another, make sure that both output hashes are encoded the same way, (e.g, hexadecimal, base64, etc).

Comment: Be aware that sha1sum and sha256sum by default read files in "text" mode, meaning they fiddle with end of lines changing the output compared to other tools. You most likely want to use them in binary mode (-b) to be able to interoperate with the rest of the world.

Answer (score 6):

**They're identical**

They both implement the same algorithm, so it's not like one can be faster than the other. Use whichever tool is available on whichever platform you use.

In Windows one uses `certUtil` as

`certUtil -hashfile <PATH_TO_FILE> <HASH_ALGORITHM>`

and, available hash algorithms are `MD2 MD4 MD5 SHA1 SHA256 SHA384 SHA512`. These are different hash algorithms with different output sizes and they provide different security/insecurity levels. One should not use MD2, MD4, MD5, or SHA-1 as long as they really know what they are doing.

Be aware of encoding, even some of the online hashings are not directly compatible, as we can see in  StackOverflow some questions are about the interoperability of the sites and libraries.

And never use online hashing for your secret/private files.